# Combine the current user posts & followers posts w/Acts_as_Follower Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to show the current_user posts and the users that he or she is following posts in a single view. For whatever reason, the posts that I've already created are not loading into the view. There are currently 5 in the database.

feed controller

```
def feed
  following_ids = current_user.following_users.map(&:id)
  @following_activities = Post.where('user_id in (?)', following_ids.push).order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

feed.html.erb

```
  <% if @following_activities.any? %>
      <% @following_activities.each do |user| %>
          <%= link_to(image_tag(user.post.avatar.url(:thumb), style: 'text-decoration: none;', class: 'round-image'), user_path(user)) %>
          <%= user.post.username %>
          <%= user.post.body %>
          <%= image_tag(user.post.photo.url(:medium), style: '') %>
      <% end %>
  <% else %>
      <h1>No new posts</h1>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are pushing nothing to the array of ids, you shall push `current_user.id`. You can make your code slightly cleaner like:

```
user_ids = current_user.following_users.pluck(:id).push(current_user.id)
@following_activities = Post.where(user_id: user_ids).order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: It's now saying undefined method 'avatar' for #<Post: .....> When I use your query method. Have any clues to why?

Answer (score 0):

In three steps, I was able to combine both, and now it's working properly.

```
def feed
    following_ids = current_user.following_users.map(&:id)
    following_ids << current_user.id
    @following_activities = Post.where(user_id: following_ids).order("created_at desc").paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```